# Angular-CLI Sass

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I am using the newest version of Angular-CLI to create an Angular2 project. I have a sass file with variables in src/assets/styles/_vars.scss. Is it possible to configure the sass compiler so I only have to write

```
@import "vars";
```

Instead of writing out the full path or relative path?

Answer (score 21):

You're in luck. See [this pr](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4003).

As an example when using sass, you'd be looking to add a `stylePreprocessorOptions` object to your app config within `angular-cli.json`. For example:

```
"apps": [
    {
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": [
                "styles" // This would point to the `my-app/src/styles` directory
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

From here, if you had a scss file such as `my-app/src/styles/_vars.scss`, you can then

```
@import 'vars'
```

across your apps scss files.

**Just remember to update `angular-cli` to at least `1.0.0-beta.26`.**

Answer (score 0):

Using `stylePreprocessorOptions` is an option and I believe this was an old workaround / feature.

Now you can just use the tilde `~` symbol like this:

```
@import '~variables';
```

I wouldn't import _underscore-files but rather have one entrypoint which makes a possible further inner structure available in one file, think of mixins, fonts, colors...

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
@import '~assets/styles/main.scss';
```